# One Application Multiple Instances and Different DB

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database-connection, multi-tenant

I am building an case management application and one of the requirements is that each client gets their own Database with their own URL. However, it is starting to be a nightmare to maintain multiple instances of the application when upgrading. I am using IIS 7 ASP.NET MVC. I would like to have one application and have the application be aware of which database to get the data from depending on the User authentication. Is there a viable alternative?

Comment: I guess those who answered assume the schema of different DBs differ between each-other. Is that so? it sounds to me as if they are the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes its better to have one instance of the application if possible otherwise it gets complicated. If the features for different clients are different then use feature flags to turn-on/turn-off features for each client/user. See below article by Martin Fowler about it. Feature flags can be per user or client. Facebook and few other major sites use feature flags effectively.

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html

Regarding the database, I think you can have a **Common database** which has all basic information including all clients and then have **other databases specific to each client** which has all other data for the client.

When any user hits a client specific URL in the **Session_Start** method of **Global.asax** add logic to fetch the appropriate connection string and store it in session (`Session["ClientDbConnectionString"]`) so that you can use it whenever you need data from client DB.

I would suggest you to store all the connection strings in a table in Common database (with a key identifying each client) so that you can add new connection string row when you want to on-board a new client. Whenever you do a new release I would suggest to update all the client databases together instead of just updating one client DB otherwise it will become unmanageable after a while.

Comment: Hi, we are doing the same thing but the issue is with the Azure session state issues. we hosted the app service in azure and it doesn't behave good with InProc session. Is there any other way to handle for azure PaaS solutions without going for session state.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is really just a tip-of-the-iceberg question. Multi-tenancy is a complex topic. Having a per-client connection to the tenant database is just one aspect. There are other aspects to consider:

- balancing of tenants: how do you ensure that tenants that grow much faster than the average get adequate resources *and* do not overwhelm other tenants that are collocated on the same storage (eg. same instance). How do you move a tenant that had grown? How do you aggregate small tenants with low activity?
- isolation of resources: a tenant can consume a large percent of resources (eg. it can run a query in the database that take sup all the CPU and starves all the other queries), how do you ensure fairness to other tenants that are collocated?
- shared data. Replicating changes to shared data (data that is common among all tenants, eg. lookup tables) *can be* problematic.
- schema changes. This is one of the trickiest topics. Database schema and code are usually changed in-sync (code expects a certain schema) and deploying a schema change to all tenants *can be* problematic.

I recommend you go over the [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) white paper. This presents three basic approaches:

- [Separate Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_sepdat)
- [Shared Database, Separate Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_sdss)
- [Shared Database, Shared Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_sdshs)

In addition, I would add the [SQL Azure Federations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597452.aspx) option (which was not available at the time the white paper was written). The paper discuss pros and cons of these approaches from database/storage point of view, considering things like:

- storage cost
- security
- availability
- scalability
- ease of schema change (app upgrade)
- extensibility

From the client side, I'm not aware of any MVC extension that helps for the multi-tenant case, something along the line of the [act_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) gem in Rails.

> is starting to be a nightmare to maintain multiple instances of the application when upgrading.

This is actually one of the biggest problems in multi-tenant architectures. Even if you have eliminated the friction of actually doing the upgrade in a DB, it is still a difficult problem to solve. Unless you can afford downtime *on all tenants* and take the entire system offline, upgrade all tenants databases, deploy new code that understands new schema, then bring all tenants online, doing it online is challenging because the app code (the ASP/MVC code) must be able to understand both versions (old and new) at once. Is not impossible to solve, but is difficult and must be coded carefully.

That being said, an important part if 'eliminating the friction of actually upgrading'. I do no what procedure you employ to deploy an upgrade. It is critical that the upgrade is automated and scripted, without any manual intervention. Diff based tools are sometimes used, like [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) from Red-Gate or even Visual Studio's [`vsdbcmd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#comparewithvsdbcmd). My favorite approach though is using upgrade scripts and metadata versioning in the application. For more details see [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/). For reference, this approach is basically the [Rails Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) approach.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to store the connection string for each user somewhere (maybe in the user table?) and look up this value whenever you create a new db-connection. This means that you can't use a connection string from web.config, but I assume you know how to create a new db-connection with a custom connection string.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you well, you need to provide [authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for each client. If client were successfully authorized, he should be redirected to his site, which means that [connection string should be changed programmatically](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2011/12/write-modify-webconfig-programmatically.html).

Alternativelly you can define the number of connection strings in web.config file. Then you can use it depends on clients authorization: [How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx)

Here is an example web.config setting:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings> 
        <add name="Client1"
            connectionString="..." 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="Client2"
            connectionString="..." 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

A problem I see in this that you now separate the application and it's database.

In a usual situation there are updated together. You now could end up with an updated application and one or more databases that aren't updated.

I think Adarsh Shah's answer is very good, but it misses this point.

My question would be: Why can't you merge those databases?

There are solutions to achieve this. For example:

Suppose you have a table names Cases. Create a view, for example Cases_V (V from view). At logon, set a session variable CompanyId (I think this is possible in SQL Server, at least it is in Oracle which I use).

In the view, filter the table on this session Variable.

The SQL of Cases_V would look like this (in oracle syntax):

```
select *
from   Cases
where  CompanyId = sys_context('USERENV', 'CLIENT_INFO'), 'CompanyId')
```

In your application you would use this view like this:

```
select *
from   Cases_V
```

This prevents users to access information from other 'installations' and minimizes maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

**AdarshShah** statement is very Correct, you should maintain the connection strings of different database in a separate MetaDatabase to simplify the process of identifying the respective connection string of the Particular client, specifically in a Multi Tenant environment you may require to roll out/allocate dedicated Database or Schema for a client, it  might become a nightmare to manage and maintain connection strings in the XML file such as SQL.Config or Web.Config.

I'm part of an organization where we specialize in building Multi Tenant Framework which could be used by ISVs, Developers to build SaaS Applications Faster without breaking their head in analyzing and understand some of the common Non Functional requirements like this. One of the Primary component of the framework is the Data Sharder, which exactly does the same.

Please have a look, http://www.techcello.com/products/saas-features

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to present how I would try to solve this issue.

First of all it is mandatory to have multiple connection strings on your application config.
I suggest you to use Entity Framework for DB Management if your app is in ASP.NET MVC.
You can build wrappers over the DbContext and ObjectContext classes(I mean you wrapper to inherit the mentioned classes), and use Factory Method to choose the context based on logged in user.

I assume that you know the database where the users are stored. So from Global.asax you are going to active that dbContext at first, and then based on user profile choose the proper context.